# How to create a times table with identity matrix?

Tags: matrices

i want to create a times table for children using my calculator and its matrix functions. How can i be successfull in this task?

Greets

Comment: Which software are you using ? Mathematically, a times table is $VV^T$ where $V$ is the column vector with entries $1,2,...9$. Why are you mentionning identity matrix ?

Comment: HiPER scientific calculator sir. Thank you for teaching me that i can transpose a matrix to create a column vector and then being able to multiply it by the simple row matrix. So useful, thanks.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know this brand name.

Comment: But how does the pocket calculator know from the outset, to highlight by matrix the quadratic numbers?

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot diagonalize it in this way. What are the matrix operations available on your pocket calculator ?

Comment: Identity matrix with whole numbers only and transpose matrix with the T exponent only if variable amongst other

Comment: When you say "identity matrix" you surely mean "diagonal matrix". With these operations only, you can't go very far...

Comment: Thank you for this bonus